# Adding link to Scrolling Image Banner breaks it.

Tags: html, css

Was following this https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/wb28eeh2/3/ to try and create a scrolling news banner for our interoffice website.

I was interested in making the images clickable links, but adding the required code around the images seems to break it, and stops the banner from moving past the first image.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

```css
/* Photo Banner */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: white;
}

.photobanner, .photobanner2 {
    height: 233px;
    width: 3550px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
}

.photobanner img, .photobanner2 img {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 height: 233px;
 width: 350px;
}

.photobanner img  {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
 
.photobanner img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    cursor: pointer;
 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}


/*keyframe animations*/
.first {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}
 
@keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2130px;}
}
 
@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2130px;}
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2130px;}
}
 
@-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2130px;}
}
 
@-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2130px;}
}

.second {
    -webkit-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
}
 
@keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2130px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
 
@-moz-keyframes bannermoves {
 0% {margin-left: -2130px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2130px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
 
@-ms-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2130px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
 
@-o-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2130px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="photobanner">
        <a href=""><img class="first" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The scrolling still works for me with the `<a>` tags added... what browser & OS are you using?

Comment: Firefox, seems to run fine on chrome, and doesnt move at all on explorer.

Comment: Using Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.first` and `.last` classes must be moved from the image tags to the anchor tags for the animation to work correctly (or you could change the CSS target `a` instead of `img`). Tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

```css
/* Photo Banner */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: white;
}

.photobanner, .photobanner2 {
    height: 233px;
    width: 3550px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
}

.photobanner img, .photobanner2 img {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 height: 233px;
 width: 350px;
}

.photobanner img  {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
 
.photobanner img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    cursor: pointer;
 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}


/*keyframe animations*/
.first {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}
 
@keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2130px;}
}
 
@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2130px;}
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2130px;}
}
 
@-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2130px;}
}
 
@-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2130px;}
}

.second {
    -webkit-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
}
 
@keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2130px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
 
@-moz-keyframes bannermoves {
 0% {margin-left: -2130px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2130px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
 
@-ms-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2130px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
 
@-o-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2130px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="photobanner">
        <a href="#" class="first"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="photobanner">
        <a href="#" class="second"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="photobanner">
        <a href="#" class="first"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```